# Apache mod_perl vs. mod_cgi: How do I decide which to use?

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi, mod-perl

What factors should I consider when deciding whether to use Apache's `mod_perl` or `mod_cgi`, when configuring an existing web application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a perl application and can run in either mode, mod_perl will be more efficient because Apache doesn't have to start a perl interpreter for every request. There's really no upside to using CGI instead.

Comment: The upside is in security in case your Perl process is compromised. Personally I think the real 'vs.' is between `mod_perl` and `fastcgi` since fastcgi offers the benefits of CGI without as much of an efficiency loss.